# How can I add a new field before writing the data received from record-edit-form?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform, create-records, js

I have an **LWC** component and I'm trying to add a new record using **record-edit-form**:

```
                  <lightning-record-edit-form
                      object-api-name={objectApiNameExpenseCard}
                      onsuccess={handleSuccessNewExpense}>
                        <lightning-layout>
                            <lightning-input-field field-name={AMOUNT}>
                            </lightning-input-field>
                        </lightning-layout>
                        <lightning-layout>
                            <lightning-input-field field-name={DATE}>
                            </lightning-input-field>
                        </lightning-layout>
                        <lightning-layout>
                            <lightning-input-field field-name={DESCRIPTION}>
                            </lightning-input-field>
                        </lightning-layout>
                        <lightning-button
                            class="slds-float_right"
                            variant="brand"
                            type="submit"
                            label="Save"
                            onclick={handleSaveNewExpense}>
                        </lightning-button>
                        <lightning-button
                            class="slds-float_right"
                            type="submit"
                            label="Cancel"
                            onclick={handleReset}>
                        </lightning-button>
                    </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

The fact is that before sending, I need to add another field (`CardKeeper__c`), which does not need to be displayed on the form. But I don't understand how to do this? Here is my **js** code:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
import EXPENSE_CARD_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Expense_Card__c';
import AMOUNT from '@salesforce/schema/Expense_Card__c.Amount__c';
import DATE from '@salesforce/schema/Expense_Card__c.CardDate__c';
import DESCRIPTION from '@salesforce/schema/Expense_Card__c.Description__c';

export default class ExpensesPage extends LightningElement {
    @api currentContact;
    @api objectApiNameExpenseCard = EXPENSE_CARD_OBJECT;
    AMOUNT = AMOUNT;
    DATE = DATE;
    DESCRIPTION = DESCRIPTION;

    handleSaveNewExpense(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        fields = event.detail.fields;
        fields.CardKeeper__c = this.currentContact.Id;
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error or what is currently happening when you submit?

Comment: Everything is fine with the shipment. The field that is not present on the form and that I am trying to add before sending is not added (`CardKeeper__c`).

Comment: what if you try `fields["CardKeeper__c"] = this.currentContact.Id;`?

Comment: Does the user have write permission on this field?

Comment: BTW, it might be easier to do this server side in a flow or trigger,  as long as you can identify the scenario during the record creation and can access the "current contact" ID.

Comment: I need to add the Id of a specific contact to this field. I'm not sure that I can somehow get it in the trigger. It would be great, because I have a trigger and additional manipulations with this data are performed in it.

Comment: @Kris I tried it, it doesn't work... I don't even understand why when trying to output the contents of the fields `const fields = event.detail.fields;`I get `undefined`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `click` event from your submit button instead of the `submit` event provided by [lightning-record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/specification). This is why when you try `event.detail.fields`, it's undefined as it's not the right event and `fields` is not being provided by the component.

```
<lightning-record-edit-form
    object-api-name={objectApiNameExpenseCard}
    onsuccess={handleSuccessNewExpense}>
    onsubmit={handleSaveNewExpense}>
.....

<lightning-button
    class="slds-float_right"
    variant="brand"
    type="submit"
    label="Save">
```

Now, when you access `fields` it should have the appropriate values and you can attempt to add an extra field

```
handleSaveNewExpense(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        fields = event.detail.fields; //provided by onsubmit
        fields["CardKeeper__c"] = this.currentContact.Id;
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, everything is as you wrote! I have already started to dig in this direction... Only here a new field is not added in this way. As a result, only three fields from the form are sent to `fields` for recording.

Comment: just tested it out, had no issues adding another field + value that wasn't on the form. Tested with lookup as well, but I was hard-coding the Id. Have you checked that `this.currentContact.Id` is not null? Or is `CardKeeper__c` the correct API name (ex. not `Card_Keeper__c`)? You can also use `console.log(JSON.stringify(fields))` before and after adding the field to see that it looks right.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I figured it out! I did everything as you wrote. The problem was related to the fact that `currentContact` is an array (I got it from another component) and I needed to specify `this.currentContact[0].Id`, but I was referring to the Id - `this.currentContact.Id`